# Hibernate query not returning results but the same query on CLI returns 1 result

Tags: java, mysql

I have a class 'Employer' that I added two columns to: eop_filename, eop_directory. I can get results running locally with a local docker instance of the database but I get no results when I put the code on the test server.

Java 11

MySQL Server version: 5.7.31-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

I added them using the following

```
ALTER TABLE Employer ADD eop_filename VARCHAR(16);
ALTER TABLE Employer ADD eop_directory VARCHAR(24);
```

I added data to one of the rows for each so that when I run the following query I get 1 result

```
mysql> select eop_filename, eop_directory FROM Employer WHERE eop_filename is not null and eop_directory is not null;
+--------------+---------------+
| eop_filename | eop_directory |
+--------------+---------------+
| XYZ_2222     | demogroup     |
+--------------+---------------+
```

In my Java code I do the following in the Repository

```
@Repository
public class EmployerDaoImpl implements EmployerDao {
   private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployerDaoImpl.class);

   private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   @Autowired
   public EmployerDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
      this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
   }

   @Override
   public List<EopSftp> getEOPFilenamePatterns() {
      try {
          String query = "SELECT eop_filename, eop_directory FROM Employer WHERE eop_filename is not null AND eop_directory is not null";
          Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query);
          List<Object[]> results = q.getResultList();
          log.info("results size: " + results.size());
    ...
```

And I get the following in the logs.

```
2020-09-25 10:51:14.403 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-193] INFO  c.a.service.EOPFileProcessingService - Begin processing EOP Files.
2020-09-25 10:51:14.566 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-193] INFO  com.als.dao.EmployerDaoImpl - results size: 0
```

My Employer class (I hate the underscores but it's following the convention of the other variable names).

```
@Entity
public class Employer() {
   ...
   @Column(length=16)
   private String eop_filename;

   @Column(length=24)
   private String eop_directory;
   
   ...
   public String getEop_filename() {
      return eop_filename;
   }

   public void setEop_filename(String eop_filename) {
      this.eop_filename = eop_filename;
   }

   public String getEop_directory() {
      return eop_directory;
   }

   public void setEop_directory(String eop_directory) {
      this.eop_directory = eop_directory;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

List<Object[]> results = q.getResultList();

=>  List results = q.getResultList();

btw show `EopSftp` class?

Comment: EopSftp class is a POJO with two variables for the filename and directory

Comment: then change to List<EopSftp> result = q.getResultList();